# Animated line graph in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, graph, flot, animated

I'd like to do a line-graph on a web-page using Javascript. I want it to be animated so that  when the page loads, the line is slowly "drawn" onto the graph.

I've managed to get a static graph working, using [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/), however I'm unsure how to animate it.

It would be half my job done to just make it draw a line *half-way* along the graph, but when I try to do this by modifying the data-set, it modifies the structure of the graph as well, so that the line fills 100% of the graph area.

So is there a way to draw the line data in stages, so I can animate it?

Or alternatively, is there some other javascript graphing framework that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Here's a simple example using Flot**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Flot Examples</title>
<link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<!--[if IE]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.pack.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.flot.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Animated Flot Example</h1>
<div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var linePoints = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];
    var i = 0;
    var arr = [[]];
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
     arr[0].push(linePoints[i]);
     $.plot($("#placeholder"), arr);
     i++;
     if(i === linePoints.length)
        clearInterval(timer);
    },300);
});
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uhmm...Why didn't I think of that +1

Answer (score 5):

Thinking outside the box (since the box that is flot is unfamiliar to me), you could just cover the graph with a div which slow recedes and displays the line. Shrinking a div in javascript is a trivial task even without third party libraries.

**Edit:**

I had to see how easy it was, so I threw this together in about 10 mins.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div style="width:480px;height:480px;position:relative;">
<img onload="setTimeout(function(){reduce();}, interval);" src="http://images.freshmeat.net/editorials/r_intro/images/line-graph-1.jpg" />
<div id="dvCover" style="position:absolute;width:370px;height:320px;background-color:white;border:solid 1px white;top:70px;left:70px;"></div>color:white;border:solid 1px blue;top:70px;left:70px;"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var step = 3;
var interval = 20;
var cover = document.getElementById("dvCover");
var currentWidth = 370;
var currentLeft = 70;
setTimeout(function(){reduce();}, interval);

function reduce()
{
    if (currentWidth > 0)
    {
        currentWidth -= step;
        currentLeft += step;
        cover.style.width = currentWidth + "px";
        cover.style.left = currentLeft + "px";

        setTimeout(function(){reduce();}, interval);
    }
    else
    {
        cover.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very simple, yet impressive +1

Comment: That's an awesome idea. Trouble is, the overlaid div would obscure the lines on the graph. But hey, it's a lot better than nothing!

Comment: @Jonathan: Depending on the complexity of your graphs background, you might be able to put a matching background on the overlay div.

Comment: @Joel Potter, yeah I thought of doing that, but it wouldn't work because ranges can be quite variable.
But I'm thinking I'll just do away with the lines, and only show the plot above a white background. May look nicer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I have written a library that focuses heavily on animation of graphs. Notice the animation during resizes. Hope this helps you and everyone else!

**LYNE.JS**

```
https://github.com/bluejamesbond/Lyne.js/tree/master
```

**GIF SAMPLE**

[image]

**LIVE SAMPLES**

```
http://bluejamesbond.github.io/Lyne.js/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could modify flot. I've made changes to the flot code before. It's fairly well-written. There's a google group if you get stuck.

Or you could just learn how to use Canvas, which is what flot uses.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add horizontal line animations to my flot charts too, unfortunately there is no plugin to do this.

please feel free to use the plugin I created to do that : http://www.codicode.com/art/jquery_flot_animator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may use d3js. Learning d3 will take some time, but it's power ie enormous and unparalleled.

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-learn-D3-js

http://big-elephants.com/2014-06/unrolling-line-charts-d3js/

A few examples of d3 visualizations:

[Official d3 Website](http://d3js.org/)

[Something I've built for an NGO](https://prayaas.iiita.ac.in/visual.php)

Answer (score 0):

I have put across a series of Graphs and Chart Libraries that would serve your purpose as well as help you create the chart or visualization that you would please. Have a look at this article http://shivganesh.com/2015/05/infovizgeek-encyclopedia-for-visualization-tools/